# javascript works on IE but doesnt on firefox and chrome

Tags: javascript, asp.net

This piece of javascript code works only on IE why and how can i make it work on firefox and chrome.
Thanks in advance.

Javascript

```
 function uploadFileChange() {
        if (document.getElementById('textbox1').value != document.getElementById("FileUpload1").value) {
            document.getElementById('textbox1').value = document.getElementById("FileUpload1").value;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

HTML/asp.net

```
<div class="fileinputs">
    <!-- Upload file invisivel-->
    <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" ClientIDMode="Static" class="file" runat="server"
        onpropertychange="uploadFileChange();" />
    <!-- button e textbox falsas para poder dar syles ao button-->
    <div class="fakefile">
        <asp:TextBox ID="textbox1" CssClass="textbox" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server"
            Width="31%" ReadOnly="true" />
        <asp:Button ID="FileChooserButton1" CssClass="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Procurar..."
            ForeColor="White" />
        <asp:Button ID="FileChooserButton2" CssClass="btnSubmit" Text="Apagar" ForeColor="White"
            OnClientClick="clear();" runat="server" />
    </div>
</div>
```

RESOLVED

Comment: How are you loading js into webpage inline or external

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The onpropertychange event is IE only so will not fire in other browsers see http://help.dottoro.com/ljufknus.php.

Use the onchange event instead http://forums.asp.net/t/1138684.aspx/1

Answer (score 0):

use alert. and try alert both the values ..u will come to know the reason..most probably other browsers returning undefined...
better to use alert and debug the values. it may b coding mistake.